# How to fake flyway migration?

Tags: flyway

Two of us made a migration script in different GIT branches. Now, I've pulled origin development branch, and I've corrected GIT merge issues, and renamed my migration script to be the last. So, the new initialization of DB and migration of DB from version of develop branch would be fine.

However, I've got a lot of data in my local testing DB, so I've manually applied new migration scripts that I've pulled in GIT. However, I can't make flyway think, that everything is okay.

So, How can I fake migrations?

When I try to migrate, I get following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.flywaydb:flyway-maven-plugin:3.2.1:migrate (default-cli) on project db: org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Validate failed. Migration Description mismatch for migration 1.118
[ERROR] -> Applied to database : AAA
[ERROR] -> Resolved locally    : BBB
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to manually update Flyway's metadata table (called `schema_version` by default)